# Query to identify Prior Fiscal Period

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write a query to identify the prior fiscal period from a table that has the date ranges for each month. I have written a working "CurrentPeriod" query with the following syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM Fiscal_Periods
WHERE (((Fiscal_Periods.EndDate)>Now()) And ((Fiscal_Periods.StartDate)<Now()));
```

One way to identify the prior period would be to subtract one from the "ID" of the result of the "CurrentPeriod" query, but I'm prompted for that value of CurrentPeriod.ID when I try to run the following  statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM Fiscal_Periods
WHERE ([CurrentPeriod].[ID])-1 =[Fiscal_Periods].[FiscalID];
```

How can I avoid being prompted for the value? Can a query reference the result of another query?

Comment: For Access? Something like `WHERE (((Fiscal_Periods.EndDate)>DateAdd ("yyyy", -1, Now())) And ((Fiscal_Periods.StartDate)<DateAdd ("yyyy", -1, Now())));`?

Comment: Awesome, I changed the "yyyy" to "m", and I got the result I was hoping to achieve.