# Query that Lists Stores to Be Opened

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write a query that determines which stores on a list need to be "opened" in the database.

I have a "Store Details" table that lists the Store's opening date, and a "Fiscal_Periods" table that lists the Start and End Dates for the Eligibility to be Opened in that Fiscal Period. I need to generate a list of stores that are eligible to be Opened in this period.

```
SELECT [Store Details].[Store Number], [Store Details].[Store Name], [Store Details].[Open Date], [Store Details].[Closed Date], [Fiscal_Periods].[EligibilityStart], [Fiscal_Periods].[EligibilityEnd]
FROM [Store Details]
WHERE ([Store Details].[Open Date] >=Fiscal_Periods.[EligibilityStart]) AND ([Store Details].[Open Date]<= [Fiscal_Periods].[EligibilityEnd]);
```

How can I make the statement compare the EligibilityStart and EligibilityEnd to the dates in the prior Fiscal_Period?

Comment: How are the `Store Details` and `Fiscal_Periods` tables related?

Comment: The `Fiscal_Periods` table contains the data necessary to determine whether the `Open Date` on the `Store Details` table is in the range to qualify it to be opened.

Comment: Access is a _relational_ database, which means that you need to specify a relationship between the two tables if you want to use them together.  Most likely, a join would be appropriate here.

Comment: Are there multiple entries in the Fiscal_Periods table? And if so: how should the database find the one responsible for a specific store?

Comment: Ok. Try to think like the daabase. You want to join or compare a store-detail record to a fiscal period. There are several entries. How do you determine, which one is the right one?

Comment: Thanks for giving me some direction on this. I can determine that by identifying what the current Fiscal Period is, perhaps by using now() or something similar. I'm unclear how to accomplish that after reviewing the w3schools.com literature. Perhaps it is a SubQuery?

Comment: Thanks @Johanness I'll give it a whirl in the AM, I'll make sure to attribute the source of such info as well.

Comment: Didnt mean show where you have it from. You had half of the answer from another question you asked but wouldnt say so. So it got much more difficult to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your WHERE-clause you didn't specifiy which Entry in the in the fiscal_period table you want to use for your comparison. In the following code I take the last row where the current date is between Start and EndDate of the Fiscal_Period and compared to that:

```
SELECT [Store Details].[Store Number], [Store Details].[Store Name], [Store Details].[Open Date], [Store Details].[Closed Date], [Fiscal_Periods].[EligibilityStart], [Fiscal_Periods].[EligibilityEnd]
FROM [Store Details]
WHERE 
(([Store Details].[Open Date])>=DLast("EligibilityStart","Fiscal_Periods","(((EndDate)>Now()) AND ((StartDate)<Now()))"))
AND
(([Store Details].[Closed Date])<=DLast("EligibilityEnd","Fiscal_Periods","(((EndDate)>Now()) AND ((StartDate)<Now()))"));
```

When you ask next time and get hints like the above, please show what you have. Especially if you already asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091955/query-to-identify-prior-fiscal-period) to that exact amount.

Comment: I tried using this code, but I get prompted for the Fiscal_Periods.EligibilityStart when I run it. None of my Eligibility ranges overlap, and all of the pertinent fields are formatted as Date in the design view of the tables.

Comment: Could always be a typo. I tried it and it worked - no matter if you have overlapping dates. It just takes the last record of the Fiscal_Periods where the EndDate is after the current Date and the StartDate is before. From that record it  gets the Eligibility-Values... So the whole thing should give you a list containing all [Store Detail]-records that opened after the Eligibility Start of the current fiscal period AND closed before the EligibilityEnd of the current fiscal period.

Comment: Yes, you definitely got me onto the right track, I had done pretty comprehensive levels of database development in what feels like a prior life, and after doing this, I am remember so much. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution by developing a query that first identifies the Prior Fiscal Period, and then creating a second query that uses the results of the first query.

```
SELECT [Store Details].*, *
FROM [Store Details], PriorPeriod
WHERE ((([Store Details].[Open Date])>=[PriorPeriod].[EligibilityStart] And ([Store Details].[Open Date])<=[PriorPeriod].[EligibilityEnd]));
```

Comment: Prior period were never a part of your question. I assume your prior period table has only one record, otherwise you'd get a mess. I wouldn't recommend this solution.